# Pyparsing: Parsing unique longest match in parentheses

Tags: context-free-grammar, pyparsing

I am trying to parse the following lines:

```
command(grep -o '(' file.txt)
command(ls -1)
```

with pyparsing. The commands are not stretching over multiple lines. The initial idea for the rule is

```
cmd = "command(" + pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.printables)) + ")"
```

but since pp.printables also contains (and should contain) the closing parenthesis ")" pyparsing cannot parse the commands. Can I force pyparsing to match the longest command string such that it is followed by a single closing parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

To look at your problem, I first created a little script containing your sample text, the parser, and a call to runTests:

```
import pyparsing as pp

tests = """\
    command(grep -o '(' file.txt)
    command(ls -1)
    """

cmd = "command(" + pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.printables)) + ")"
cmd.runTests(tests)
```

As you said, this fails since the terminating ")" gets inncluded in the `OneOrMore` reptetition:

```
command(grep -o '(' file.txt)
                             ^
FAIL: Expected ")" (at char 29), (line:1, col:30)

command(ls -1)
              ^
FAIL: Expected ")" (at char 14), (line:1, col:15)
```

(`runTests` is useful here since it will either display the parsed results, or put out a marker where the parser went astray.)

This happens because pyparsing is purely left-to-right, with no implied lookahead.

The simplest immediate fix is to exclude ')' from the set of printables that your words can be made of:

```
cmd = "command(" + pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars=")")) + ")"
```

And this gives the successful output:

```
command(grep -o '(' file.txt)
['command(', 'grep', '-o', "'('", 'file.txt', ')']

command(ls -1)
['command(', 'ls', '-1', ')']
```

But if I add a different test string to your tests:

```
command(grep -o ')' file.txt)
```

The `')'` is mistaken for the closing right paren:

```
command(grep -o ')' file.txt)
                  ^
FAIL: Expected end of text (at char 18), (line:1, col:19)
```

Typically when including expressions in pyparsing of the "read up until X" variety, we need to make sure that an X inside quotes is not misinterpreted as an actual X.

One way to do this is to pre-empt the match by looking for quoted strings before matching printable words:

```
cmd = "command(" + pp.OneOrMore(pp.quotedString | 
                                pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars=")")) + ")"
```

And now our quoted right paren is correctly stepped over as being a quoted string:

```
command(grep -o ')' file.txt)
['command(', 'grep', '-o', "')'", 'file.txt', ')']
```

But there are still a number of possible corner cases that could trip up this parser, so it may be simpler to use a pyparsing `SkipTo` expression:

```
cmd = "command(" + pp.SkipTo(")", ignore=pp.quotedString) + ")"
```

which runs the tests as:

```
command(grep -o '(' file.txt)
['command(', "grep -o '(' file.txt", ')']

command(ls -1)
['command(', 'ls -1', ')']

command(grep -o ')' file.txt)
['command(', "grep -o ')' file.txt", ')']
```

Note that we also have to explicitly tell `SkipTo` to step over any ")" characters that might be inside a quoted string. Also, the body of our command parameters are now returned as a single string.

If your command body might itself contain parenthetical values, then we still trip up on them. Look at this test:

```
command(grep -x '|'.join(['(', ')']) file.txt)
```

runTests shows us that again, we have been misled by a ')' that we didn't want to end with:

```
command(grep -x '|'.join(['(', ')']) file.txt)
                                     ^
FAIL: Expected end of text (at char 37), (line:1, col:38)
```

You can add a lookahead for the ')' to tell SkipTo to only match the ')' that is right before the end of the string:

```
cmd = "command(" + pp.SkipTo(")" + pp.FollowedBy(pp.StringEnd()), 
                             ignore=pp.quotedString) + ")"
```

But with this parser, we have practically reverted to what you could do just as well with string index, split, and strip methods.

One final version to show you uses pyparsing's `nestedExpr`, which will help you get around the case of nested parentheses inside your argument list:

```
cmd = "command" + pp.originalTextFor(pp.nestedExpr())
```

Normally, `nestedExpr` will return the parsed contents as a nested list of lists of strings, but by wrapping it with `originalTextFor`, we get the original values. Note also that we removed the '(' from the opening 'command(', since `nestedExpr` will use that to parse its opening parenthesis, with these results:

```
command(grep -o '(' file.txt)
['command', "(grep -o '(' file.txt)"]

command(ls -1)
['command', '(ls -1)']

command(grep -o ')' file.txt)
['command', "(grep -o ')' file.txt)"]

command(grep -x '|'.join(['(', ')']) file.txt)
['command', "(grep -x '|'.join(['(', ')']) file.txt)"]
```

Ultimately, the approach you take and the complexity of parser you need will depend on your goals for this parser. But these examples should give you some ideas on how to expand from here.